# Google charts - Labels are not showing

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

I was trying to create 3 charts using google charts in a single line.but it not showing the labels for the values and we can see there is lot of space was vacant in between the charts.is there any way to remove that space and show the labels properly in the graph?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 5],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    pieHole: '0.5',

    legend: {
      position: 'labeled',
      labeledValueText: 'both',
      textStyle: {
        color: 'blue',
        fontSize: 14
      }
    },
  };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart2'));
  var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart3'));
  options.title = 'industries For USA';
  chart1.draw(data, options);
  options.title = 'Categories For USA';
  chart2.draw(data, options);
  options.title = 'Categories For Construction';
  chart3.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.chart-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.top-five-charts {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="top-five-charts">
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <div id="chart1" class="insight-pie"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <div id="chart2" class="insight-pie"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <div id="chart3" class="insight-pie"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output in normal screen

[image]

Comment: sizing google's `PieChart` is the worst -- to reduce gaps between charts, use option --> `chartArea.width = '100%'` -- but this will not fix labels --- to show labels, use option --> `legend.position = 'top'` -- instead of `'labeled'` and remove `fontSize`, `14` is too big --- but this will bring back gaps...

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line on your JavaScript code before drawing the charts:

```
options.chartArea = {left: '10%', width: '100%', height: '65%'};
```

I've also changed the legend font size to 10.

It will look like this:
[image: adjusted pie charts]

Here's the JSFiddle illustrating it: https://jsfiddle.net/6r3ms2tz/

Comment: This creates the same output

Comment: Did you check the JSFiddle? Don't forget to also change the font size to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look responsive design principles and please check out this link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart

Simply change: 'legend':'right' according to the your choice.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, below worked:

Code:

```
let options = {
  legend: {
    position: "labeled",
  },
  chartArea: {
    width: "100%"
  }
};
```

HTML for my case is below because I am using https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts

```
  <google-chart
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  >
  </google-chart>
```

HTML for your case:

```
<div id="chart1" class="insight-pie" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ></div>
```

Hope that helps.